# Lower bounds on comparison sorts for a small fraction of inputs?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, math, big-o, proof

Can someone please walk me through mathematical part of the solution of the following problem.

Show that there is no comparison sort whose running time is linear for at least half
of the n! inputs of length n. What about a fraction of 1/n of the inputs of length n?
What about a fraction (1/(2)^n)?

Solution:

If the sort runs in linear time for m input permutations, then the height h of the
portion of the decision tree consisting of the m corresponding leaves and their
ancestors is linear.
Use the same argument as in the proof of Theorem 8.1 to show that this is impossible
for m = n!/2, n!/n, or n!/2n.
We have 2^h ≥ m, which gives us h ≥ lgm. For all the possible ms given here,
lgm = Ω(n lg n), hence h = Ω(n lg n).
In particular,

```
    lgn!/2= lg n! − 1 ≥ n lg n − n lg e − 1
    lgn!/n= lg n! − lg n ≥ n lg n − n lg e − lg n
    lgn!/2^n= lg n! − n ≥ n lg n − n lg e − n
```

Comment: Related: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/133314/755

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each of these proofs are a straightforward modification of the more general proof that you can't have a comparison sort that sorts any faster than Ω(n log n) (you can see this proof **[in this earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7155425/501557)**).  Intuitively, the argument goes as follows.  In order for a sorting algorithm to work correctly, it has to be able to determine what the initial ordering of the elements is.  Otherwise, it can't reorder the values to put them in ascending order.  Given n elements, there are n! different permutations of those elements, meaning that there are n! different inputs to the sorting algorithm.

Initially, the algorithm knows nothing about the input sequence, and it can't distinguish between any of the n! different permutations.  Every time the algorithm makes a comparison, it gains a bit more information about how the elements are ordered.  Specifically, it can tell whether the input permutation is in the group of permutations where the comparison yields true or in the group of permutations where the comparison yields false.  You can visualize how the algorithm works as a binary tree, where each node corresponds to some state of the algorithm, and the (up to) two children of a particular node indicate the states of the algorithm that would be entered if the comparison yields true or false.

In order for the sorting algorithm to be able to sort correctly, it has to be able to enter a unique state for each possible input, since otherwise the algorithm couldn't distinguish between two different input sequences and would therefore sort at least one of them incorrectly.  This means that if you consider the number of leaf nodes in the tree (parts where the algorithm has finished comparing and is going to sort), there must be at least one leaf node per input permutation.  In the general proof, there are n! permutations, so there must be at least n! leaf nodes.  In a binary tree, the only way to have k leaf nodes is to have height at least Ω(log k), meaning that you have to do at least Ω(log k) comparisons.  Thus the general sorting lower bound is Ω(log n!) = Ω(n log n) by Stirling's approximation.

In the cases that you're considering, we're restricting ourselves to a subset of those possible permutations.  For example, suppose that we want to be able to sort n! / 2 of the permutations.  This means that our tree must have height at least lg (n! / 2) = lg n! -  1 = Ω(n log n).  As a result. you can't sort in time O(n), because no linear function grows at the rate Ω(n log n).  For the second part, seeing if you can get n! / n sorted in linear time, again the decision tree would have to have height lg (n! / n) = lg n! - lg n = Ω(n log n), so you can't sort in O(n) comparisons.  For the final one, we have that lg n! / 2<sup>n</sup> = lg n! - n = Ω(n log n) as well, so again it can't be sorted in O(n) time.

However, you can sort 2<sup>n</sup> permutations in linear time, since lg 2<sup>n</sup> = n = O(n).

Hope this helps!

Comment: one question arises for me: what about 1/c when c is constant? can we say 1/c * n! <= 2^n is not hold then again with this case there is no linear time sorting?