# Priority queue O(1) insertion and removal

Tags: data-structures

Is it possible for a priority queue to have both O(1) insertion and removal?

Priority queues can be implemented using heaps and looking at the run times for Fibonacci heaps it appears that it is not possible to get a run time better than O(logN) per removal.

I am trying to implement a data structure where given N items I will have half in a max-priority queue and half in a min-priority queue. I am then to remove all N items sequentially.

I can insert all N elements in O(N) time but removing all N items will take O(N*logN) so I am wondering if another approach would be more suitable.

Comment: If you could have O(1) insertion and O(1) removal, you could use that to sort a list in O(n) time. And you're not supposed to be able to do that in the general case. So that strongly argues against the possibility.

Comment: @harold To elaborate, there is a mathematical *proof* that a comparison sort of N elements must make a number of comparisons proportional to `N log N`. So unless you find a fatal flaw in a decade-old result that's been peer-reviewed to death, that's it. **However**, for specific kinds of data, such as integers, you *can* do better because you can do more than comparisons (e.g. bucketing them or using them as indices for a random access collection). The same could conceivably apply to priority queues. But to be honest, I've never heard of such a data structure.

Comment: @harold- You really should post that as an answer - I was going to, but I'd feel bad stealing your reputation points. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you could construct a priority queue with O(1) insertion and O(1) removal, you could use that to sort a list of n items in O(n) time. As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7155425/555045), you can't sort in O(n) in the general case, so it will be impossible to construct a priory queue with O(1) insertion and O(1) removal without making more assumptions on the input.

For example, a priority queue that has O(1) insertion and O(k) (k is the maximum element that could be inserted) removal can be constructed. Keep a table of k linked lists. Insertion of `x` just prepends an item to the front of the `x`th list. Removal has to scan through the table to find the first non-empty list (then remove the first item of the list and return the index of that list). There are only k lists, so removal takes O(k) time. If k is a constant, that works out to O(1) removal.

In practice, using a table of counts would work out better. Incrementing a variable-length integer isn't constant time unless you use amortized analysis (which is why I didn't use it in the previous paragraph), but in practice you wouldn't need variable-length counts anyway. Also, in practice it would be bad for large k, even if k is a constant - you'd run out of memory quickly and scanning for the first non-zero element could take a while.

Comment: Sorry to bump this nearly 9 years later, but do you know of any approaches that would work in the case of fixed-size unsigned integers? Since we can sort those in O(n) time with radix sort, I imagine it would be possible, but I have no idea how one would go about doing so.

Comment: @LevKnoblock a trie would do it, for example 32 bit keys could be put in a radix 256 trie of 4 layers (the bottom layer can be bit-arrays if you want). Insertion and popMin take O(length) time, and the length is a small constant.