# Returning the Min of 3 variables without using an array

Tags: java, min

I have three variables a b c. I want a way (in java) of selecting the Min of these variables and adding 1 to it without using an array to sort the values.

Is there a way to do this ?

At the beginning of the program all these variables will be equal to zero.

Comment: Yes there are lots of ways to do it. What have you tried?

Comment: Use Math.min:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576557/most-efficient-way-to-find-smallest-of-3-numbers-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Math.min(Math.min(a,b), c) + 1`

Answer (score 2):

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 3;

int min = Math.min(a, Math.min(b, c)) + 1;
```